# Set HTML5 Canvas Height And Width And Having Content Inside Scale

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Is it possible to set the width and height of a canvas element and have the existing content scale to fit these new dimensions?

Right now the user uploads an image and my page creates a canvas element containing this image and whose dimensions are the same size as the image.  I want to limit the size that I'm working with, however, so here is an example of what I want to have happen:

1. The user uploads an image that is 1600 x 1200 pixels (Not saved to server)
2. The data goes right to an html5 canvas object
3. The canvas height and width are set to 800 x 600 and the image content scales appropriately and then is displayed.

Right now if I set the canvas width and height it just crops the image at those dimension, not resizing as I would like.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to call `drawImage`

One is:

`ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh)`

Where dx,dy,dw,dh are the destination x, y, width, and height.

If you make dw and dh always 800x600, the image will drawn will always automatically be scaled to 800x600.

Here's a tiny example that will always draw any size image to 800x600 http://jsfiddle.net/jAT8Y/

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use context.scale function. Your image quality will remain better if you use scale.